# In Sympy, how to set assumptions so the simplify() function will work on this piecewise function?

Tags: python, sympy

I am manually computing a Fourier transform and sympy is returning a piecewise function based on conditions for n. The code I am using is:

```
from sympy import *

n, p, x = symbols('n p x')

def F(x):
    return (2/pi)*(pi**2 - x**2)

A = F(x).integrate((x, 0, pi))

def F(x):
    return (2/pi)*(pi**2 - x**2)*cos(n*x) 

A1 = F(x).integrate((x, 0, pi)).simplify()

display(A1)
```

The output I am getting is:

[image: the output]

How would I set the assumptions of n to be between negative and positive infinity and also not zero? Additionally, this ought to simplify to `(4*(-1)**(n+1))/n**2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have this:

```
In [21]: (2*(-x**2 + pi**2)*cos(n*x)/pi).integrate((x, 0, pi)).simplify()                                                         
Out[21]: 
⎧4⋅(-π⋅n⋅cos(π⋅n) + sin(π⋅n))                            
⎪────────────────────────────  for n > -∞ ∧ n < ∞ ∧ n ≠ 0
⎪               3                                        
⎪            π⋅n                                         
⎨                                                        
⎪               2                                        
⎪            4⋅π                                         
⎪            ────                      otherwise         
⎩             3
```

The condition in the piecewise is that n is (real) finite and nonzero.

I'm not sure what it is you want but here are some possibilities:

```
In [14]: n = Symbol('n', nonzero=True)                                                                                           

In [15]: (2*(-x**2 + pi**2)*cos(n*x)/pi).integrate((x, 0, pi)).simplify()                                                         
Out[15]: 
4⋅(-π⋅n⋅cos(π⋅n) + sin(π⋅n))
────────────────────────────
               3            
            π⋅n             

In [16]: n = Symbol('n', integer=True)                                                                                            

In [17]: (2*(-x**2 + pi**2)*cos(n*x)/pi).integrate((x, 0, pi)).simplify()                                                         
Out[17]: 
⎧       n            
⎪-4⋅(-1)             
⎪─────────  for n ≠ 0
⎪     2              
⎪    n               
⎨                    
⎪     2              
⎪  4⋅π               
⎪  ────     otherwise
⎪   3                
⎩                    

In [18]: n = Symbol('n', integer=True, nonzero=True)                                                                              

In [19]: (2*(-x**2 + pi**2)*cos(n*x)/pi).integrate((x, 0, pi)).simplify()                                                         
Out[19]: 
       n 
-4⋅(-1)  
─────────
     2   
    n
```